# Avoid Duplicate in Mysql Left Join Query

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

i have to take data from three tables like Userdetails,tasks,timedetails so i am getting data but it is duplicating based on the timedetails table. for example person id is - 1. it is presented two times in timedetails table then i'm getting duplicate rows. 
my query is

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(B.task_status) as task_status,
        GROUP_CONCAT(B.task_type) as task_type,
        GROUP_CONCAT(B.task_id) as task_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(B.task_name) as task_name,
        A.us_id,
        A.us_name,
        C.out_time
FROM    ts_userdetails A
LEFT JOIN
        cms_task B
ON      B.emp_id = A.us_id
LEFT JOIN
        ts_timedetails C
ON      C.user_id=A.us_id
WHERE   C.entry_date='2017-05-09' AND
        A.us_id!='1'
GROUP BY C.user_id
```

I am getting results like
[image]

I don't want duplicated things in displayed fields.

If I have 2 timedetails for one particular person id means 2 times duplication occurs. I just want one time.

Comment: Please add your input, your result and the result you'd want as well formatted text. That image is barely readable without a magnifier...

Comment: It seems like a really un-useful result. Just saying.

Comment: we are using this result for report purpose

Answer (score 1):

use `distinct` keyword

```
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(distinct B.task_status) as task_status,GROUP_CONCAT(distinct B.task_type) as task_type,GROUP_CONCAT(distinct B.task_id) as task_id,GROUP_CONCAT(distinct B.task_name) as task_name,A.us_id,A.us_name,C.out_time FROM ts_userdetails A LEFT JOIN cms_task B ON B.emp_id = A.us_id LEFT JOIN ts_timedetails C ON C.user_id=A.us_id WHERE C.entry_date='2017-05-09' AND A.us_id!='1' GROUP BY C.user_id
```

Comment: if i put distinct before group concat then status i will not get for all tasks. status are fixed 0,1,2

Comment: If you look into the query you will notice that `distinct` is placed inside `group_concat`  meaning it will affect only it's contents...

Comment: Ah, I think I get you...well, that's not possible. you either have distinct values in group_concat or get all the duplicates.